# How to override sorting mechanism of Enterprise Architect project browser?

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I am creating EA packages, elements and attributes through C# Addins. By default all these elements will be stored in sorted order in EA project browser.

Is there any way to store EA packages, elements and attributes in insertion order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **TreePos** Property might help for sorting the elements under package through API  **Element.TreePos**.
2. If you need to update the table directly then need to use **TPos** column of the **t_Object** table.

Please refer in sparx help for more details under element class or project class for TreePos.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
How we are going to apply insertion sort for EA attributes ?

Comment: For attributes i think  Pos property.

Comment: but we have attribute.pos api to position the attributes inside the class list.

Comment: Yes sorryy my bad . Yes you can use that property in attribute class and to update directly in table can use Pos column in t_attribute table

Comment: By using attribute.pos we can sort the order.

Answer (score 1):

For attributes you can try using the attribute pos which will position of the attribute in the Class attribute list